# strings in fortran and filenames using them

Tags: string, fortran

here is the trouble ... i'm dynamically building (rather changing)a string which contains numerals(numbers) (like to have filename out01.txt ,out02.txt etc ..)

my program works fine (i'm using the last updated value string to name a file and edit that file) ... but in the same directory with "ls" command, i can see that file created and through file browser i can acess it but from command line using vim , gedit i can't open it new file of same name is opening... moreover i can't remove that file from command line (rm out010.txt'
no such file or directory) here is the code , i might not have been able to explain my problem but code will speak for itself ...

```
program strtest
implicit none
 character(len=1024)::filen,format_str
 integer::i
 format_str="(a5,i0.3,'.txt')"
 do i=1,10 
  write(filen,format_str)'out',i
 end do
write(*,*)trim(filen)
open(23,file=trim(filen))
write(23,*)"what a mess!"
close(23)
stop
end program strtest
```

note: i have the same problem even without using trim() function in file opening statement

please explain my situation!!

regards ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your filenames are coming out with 2 spaces in front of them, so if you put `rm "  out01.txt"` (2 spaces,out01.txt) you will be able to delete them.  It's the a5 that's throwing off the format string.

Answer (score 7):

As @jonsca pointed out already, the problem is with the extra whitespace. The simplest way to get rid of it is to use `adjustl`, like this:

```
open(23,file=trim(adjustl(filen)))
```

Comment: If the OP changes the format string to a3 you won't need the overhead of one of the function calls.

Comment: @Zhenya actually ... i understand that .. but i intend (though not written) take the outfile(just initial one)name from user and use it for filenaming (of course with length restrictions may be a14 perhaps ..)..

Comment: You should be able to omit the field width and simply use "A" as the format, in which case the length of the data item is used.

Comment: @jonsca: It's a personal preference, of course, but I'd much rather avoid using format strings altogether, and I would not worry the slightest on function call overhead in here. 
@Vasu: In such cases I would just reserve a string of, like, CHARACTER*99, and use trim(adjustl(filen)).

Comment: Not to take this OT, but what would you use in place of a format string?  Direct manipulation of the string itself?